# How to expand a directory under Favorites in Windows Explorer sidebar

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, favorites, sidebar

I can collapse and expand any directory in the Windows Explorer sidebar, except for those folders I have added to my Favorites. How do I enable the collapse/expand triangle? A third-party app would be fine.

[image: Windows Explorer sidebar, showing expandable directories, except for Favorites.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, You can't. They're links, not folders